# how to capture the data sent by alloy ui io request in serveresource method?

Tags: liferay-6, alloy-ui

Getting blank values for title and description in serveResource method.Is this the right way to send the parameters from io request?

After inserting blank values in database I have to reload the page to see the inserted values?So io-request is not ajax request?

```
    <aui:script use="aui-base">
        A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>save').on('click', function(event) {
        var A = AUI();
        var title=A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>title').val();
        alert(title);
        var description=A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>description');

                    var url = '<%= newJob.toString() %>';
                    A.io.request(
                        url,
                        {

                            method:'POST',
                            data: {
                                <portlet:namespace />title: title,
                                <portlet:namespace />description: description,
                                    },


                        }
                            ['aui-io-deprecated']

                            );
                            Liferay.Util.getOpener().<portlet:namespace/>closePopup('<portlet:namespace/>dialog'); 
        });
```

Comment: A possible alternative would be to build the resourceURL in the javascript and supply the data as parameters.

Comment: the url that I have passed in the above script is resourceURL only..

Comment: I meant replace `var url = '<%= newJob.toString() %>';` with `var url=Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();` and then add the `title` and `description` values as parameters manually. I thought I had done that as a workaround in the past, but didn't get it to work for me in this case. I was able to get the values from the request, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUI's io request is ajax request only.

You can get parameters in serveResource method using code below:

```
ParamUtil.get(resourceRequest, "NAMEOFPARAMETER");
```

Modify your javascript function and provide data attribute as below:

```
 data: {
       '<portlet:namespace />title': title,
       '<portlet:namespace />description': description,
       }
```

Comment: can you try adding one more attribute `dataType: 'text',` and check

Comment: Can you trace ajax call using Chrom developer tool or Firefox under Network tab and see what POST data its passing to server?

Comment: title, description fields were normal input fields but not aui:input fields in my jsp. I was not adding <portlet:namespace/> to name attribute of input field. I  was getting null values for that reason only.

Answer (score 0):

I assume both `title` and `description` are textfields. If so, `description` is missing a `.val()` call, or more appropriately, `.get('value')`. I didn't use a dialog/modal in my source, but the overall approach should be the same.

```
<script>
  AUI().use('aui-base', 'aui-io-request', function(A){
    A.one('#<portlet:namespace />save').on('click', function(event) {
         var title= A.one('#<portlet:namespace />title').get('value');
         var description=A.one('#<portlet:namespace />description').get('value');

         var url = '<%=myResourceURL.toString()%>';

         A.io.request(url,
                      {
                         method:'POST',
                         data: {
                                title: title,
                                description: description,
                               },
                         });
                      });
  });
</script>
```

I'm still relatively new to Liferay and have had trouble with this as well. I've noticed that the `data` parameters are not in the `parametersMap` of the default `ResourceRequest`, as you have stated. Out of curiosity, I decided to use

```
UploadPortletRequest req = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(resourceRequest);
```

in the `serveResource` method and check it's `parametersMap`. The `title` and `description` parameters are available therein. I'm still learning where and how to access data from Liferay objects, but it would seem that for the `UploadPortletRequest` to have the data, it would be plucked from somewhere within the default `ResourceRequest` ... where still remains elusive to me.

---

*After inserting blank values in database I have to reload the page to see the inserted values?*

You have to reload the page because a `resource` action does not trigger a page refresh. If you are manipulating data that you want reflected in some other "view" you'll need to configure the appropriate communication or use one of the other available url types that does trigger the `doView` method of your other "view".